# What is the meaning of "while away"? The meaning and usage

Tags: word-usage

The meaning and usage of the phrase

> while away my old age

.

Answer (score 1):

To "while away" a period of time is to pass it pleasantly and unremarkably. You might "while away an afternoon" reading, or "while away the summer" going for walks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the SOED 'while' as a verb has the meaning to pass through a vacant time. I was surprised to see that usage recorded (as long ago as 1635) because I had always thought that in that context the word was 'wile'.

The SOED records that spelling in that context in 1796.

Given a choice, I think that 'while' as a verb is confusing, and would use 'wile' but anyone can choose whichever spelling they prefer.

Comment: That would have the problem of leaving your readers reaching for their dictionary. After all, that spelling seems more likely to evoke a never-used singular of "wiles" than the phrase "while away" that is very common.